# How can I convert string to array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

This is the string `Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true` I want to convert it to array of objects like this

Is This Possible In javaScript Nodejs????
thanks in Advance.

```
[
  {
    "option": "Option 1",
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "option": "Option 2",
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "option": "Option 3",
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "option": "Option 4",
    "value": true
  }
]
```

Comment: I like one liners .... `const result = "Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true".split('|').map((option, i, a) => i % 2 ? null : {option, value: a[i+1]}).filter(x => x)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could split and iterate the array.

```js
const
    string = 'Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true',
    result = [];

for (let i = 0, a = string.split('|'); i < a.length; i += 2) {
    const
        option = a[i],
        value = JSON.parse(a[i + 1]);
    result.push({ option, value });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's funny how the Queen of reduce uses a for loop this time. But it might be faster when you skip each second element

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.match()` on the string with a regular expression to get an array of the form:

```
[["Option 1", "false"], ...]
```

And then map each key-value into an object like so:

```js
const str = "Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true";
const res = str.match(/[^\|]+\|[^\|]+/g).map(
  s => (([option, value]) => ({option, value: value==="true"}))(s.split('|'))
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const options = 'Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true';

const parseOptions = options => options.split('|').reduce((results, item, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    results.push({ option: item });
  } else {
    results[results.length - 1].value = item === 'true';
  }
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(parseOptions(options));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
str='Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true';
str=str.split('|');
result=[];
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i += 2){
result.push({"option":str[i],"value":str[i+1]=="true"?true:false})
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `str[i+1]=="true"?true:false` there is no need for a ternary here as `str[i+1]=="true"` gives the same result

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly more functional solution to the problem, which I think is more semantic

```
const str = 'Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true';
const parsed = str
    .match(/[^\|]+\|[^\|]+/g)
    .map(matchedValues => {
        const [option, value] = matchedValues.split('|');
        return Object.fromEntries([['option', option], ['value', JSON.parse(value)]]);
    })

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: Fair enough. I added the `JSON.parse` but idea is still the same..

Answer (score 0):

With `Array.prototype.reduce` you can *morph* the array from `String.prototype.split` into an object.

```js
const str = "Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true";
const arr = str.split('|')

const obj = arr.reduce((carry, elem, index, orig) => {
  if (index % 2) { return carry }
  carry.push({"option": orig[index], "value": !!orig[index+1]});
  return carry;
}, [])

console.log(obj)
```

Or a more exotic approach with double split

```js
const str = "Option 1|false|Option 2|false|Option 3|false|Option 4|true";
const arr = (str+"|").match(/[^|]+\|[^|]+(?=\|)/g);

const res = arr.reduce((carry, item) => {
  let [option, value] = item.split('|');
  carry.push({option, value: !!value});
  return carry;
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right. I edited my answer. Didn't read the OP thoroughly enough